# Linux snap unison-jz package ssh connection always prompts for passphrase

Tags: ssh, unison, keychain

In looking toward upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.1, I think I will
have some machines on 18.04 for a while.  I decided to install
the unison-jz snap to prevent a version mismatch.  Even though I
have an ssh-agent running, I keep it around with [keychain](https://linux.die.net/man/1/keychain),
and I am able to login to my remote host without a passphrase
prompt outside of unison-jz, it always prompts me for the
passphrase for my id_rsa file.

I have tried to compare the output of `ssh -v` from both
ssh and unison-jz's invocation of ssh (by setting `sshargs = -v` in my preferences file, but I cannot tell what the
difference is.

Any suggestions for what to do next?

Comment: Read `man ssh-add ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator, but "I am able to login to my remote host without a passphrase prompt outside of unison-jz"  So I have all of the usual ssh-agent, ssh-add mechanisms working.  They just don't work with the ssh invoked by unison-jz.  I am trying to figure out why not.